# Something went wrong when adding account

Tags: windows-10

Here is an image of the error:

[image: error]

I do not know why this keeps on happening but whenever I try to add a google account to my surface go tablet this error happens.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/329936/you-receive-the-0x80004005-the-operation-failed-error-message-when-you

Comment: https://appuals.com/solved-how-to-fix-error-0x80004005/

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I don't use norton, I use windows defender.

Comment: Please read the other one as well. If not caused by some AV then you have corrupted system files or some other situation mentioned. The point being is easy to google those errors by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my personal understanding, it is recommended that you use the following two methods:

**Method 1: Turning off Firewall and other Applications**

One workaround which worked for many people was disabling Firewall applications (including Windows Firewall, Windows Defender, and other Antivirus applications). It seems that because of some bug, these applications conflict and restrain you from switching into the local account.

1. **Turn off all firewall/antivirus applications**. You check the article on [how to disable Windows Firewall](https://appuals.com/how-to-disable-windows-firewall/).
2. Once all the applications are closed, try changing into a Local Account without using any password.
3. Sign out and finish. **Restart** your computer to make sure that the changes have been implemented.

**Method 2: Making a New Local Account and linking it**

we can try making a new local account and deleting the old one. Make sure that you have an external hard drive so you can back up all your data and configurations and restore it back when you create the new account.

1. Press **Windows + S**, type “**command prompt**”, right-click on the application and select “**Run as administrator**”.
2. Once in elevated command prompt, execute the following command:
   **net user “UserName” /add**

Here “Username” in the name of the account you are trying to add to the computer.

3. Once the account is added to the computer, restart your computer and log in to that local account. Do note that you should make it administrator using the current account before logging into it. Check if all the functions are working properly before transferring your backed up data.
4. If all the aspects are working properly, use the new local account to delete your old one. Your password might be required when deleting the old account.